# ngblur and ngfocus on options list shown / hidden in Angular

Tags: angularjs

When using select and option the ngblur isn't triggered once I click off the list without selecting anything.

I need to know when the options of the select and shown or hidden. Is there a directive that supports this ?

I can use ngblur and ngfocus on the Select element but nothing is ever fired on the options being shown or hidden. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run some tests on fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/EternalLight/x7dxkok2/

```
<div ng-app="testTt">
    <div ng-controller="Controller" style="padding:2em;"> 
    <select ng-focus="onFocus()" ng-blur="onBlur()">
        <option>Test 1</option>
        <option>Test 2</option>
    </select>  
    <p>{{status}}</p>  
    </div>
</div>
```

It seems that the blur event is fired when you click outside of the element when the option list is hidden. When you open the option list, and then click outside, the `<select>` is still in focus - you can see it by the blue (or any other, depending on your browser) outline around it. Honestly, I would use ng-blur, since it takes another outside click to trigger it, and there's no way for a user to get around it.